# Get Parent Frame object from JPanel object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, netbeans-7

**Is it possible to get the parent `JFrame` object from `JPanel` class??** 
Actually I am trying to make a GUI using NetBeans.The GUI has a Frame and Two panels.
**1)** Login Panel (having two text field and button)
**2)** Second Panel 
When JFrame loaded, I add `LoginPanel` in it initially.

```
public ParentJFrame() {    //in constructor
        initComponents();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBounds(300,300, 300, 300);
        this.getContentPane().add(new LoginPanel());

    }
```

After click on button (of LoginPanel) , I am trying to remove `LoginPanel` from JFrame and adding `SecondPanel`.
Now I am removing `LoginPanel` and adding `SecondPanel` in `LoginPanel` class where I can access the `username , password` fields but here I am unable to get the JFrame object from which I have to remove this component.
If I try this in `ParentJFrameClass` then it is not possible for me to access `username , password` field's value. **(As this is the structure provided by netbeans)**
So what Should I do now? What would be the solution in this case
I hope I have explained the problem in detail but in case if anything is not clear please let me know
Experts Please help

Comment: [SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent(java.awt.Component))

Comment: can you elaborate please ..

Comment: You should use a `CardLayout` read more in [CardLayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: How `CardLayout` will help in this scenario

Comment: Well cardlayout it's an advice read the tutorial and you could switch with panel1 and panel2 without "removing",as for your question with `windowForCOmponent` you'll obtain your desired `jframe`  object. Then you have to downcasting to your netbeans jframe creation(ParentJFrameClass).

Answer (score 1):

To use cardlayout to change between the panels,like follwing code may help you,you need to modify it to meet your need:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * replace the real panel of yours 
 * do the right process
*/

public class CardLayoutLoginDemo  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JFrame frame = new LoginFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
class LoginFrame extends JFrame {
   public LoginFrame() {
       super("CardLayout Demo");

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        mainPanel.add(getFirstPanel(), FIRST);
        mainPanel.add(getSecondPanel(), SECOND);
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
   }
   //use your first panel
   private JPanel getFirstPanel() {
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
       panel.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
       panel.add(new JTextField(10));
       panel.add(new JLabel("password: "));
       panel.add(new JTextField(10));
       JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
       JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
       btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mainPanel.getLayout());
                cl.show(mainPanel, SECOND);
        }
       });
       btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
       panel.add(btnLogin);
       panel.add(btnCancel);
       return panel;
   }
   //use the second panel
   private JPanel getSecondPanel() {
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
       panel.add(new JLabel("Second panel"));
       panel.add(new JLabel("other processs"));
       JButton btnOther = new JButton("Ok");
       JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
       panel.add(btnOther);
       panel.add(btnBack);
       btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mainPanel.getLayout());
                 cl.show(mainPanel, FIRST);
            }
        });
       return panel;
   }
   private final String FIRST = "First panel";
   private final String SECOND = "Second panel";
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JPanel mainPanel;
}
```